# TransformBlock Items get stuck in the output queue. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have walked through the TPL DataFlow and have faced a very irritating problem occurred in the code using `TrasformBlock` linked to `ActionBlock`.

Eventually I have found that items got stuck in `TransformBlock`'s output queue, since its `OutputCount` property continuously returned the value higher than "0".
That's why the whole application deadlocked. However, it unblocks as soon as I call `TransformBlock.TryReceiveAll()`.

Can anyone, please, let me know if there is something I missed or how to prevent such behavior?

```
static void Main()
{
    int total = 0;
    int itemsProcessing = 0;

    TransformBlock<int, Tuple<int, double>> transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, Tuple<int, double>>(
        i => new Tuple<int, double>(i, Math.Sqrt(i)),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 20,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
        });

    ActionBlock<Tuple<int, double>> outputBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, double>>(async tuple =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); // simulating data output delay
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref itemsProcessing);
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 5,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
        });

    transformBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(t => outputBlock.Complete());

    using (Timer timer = new Timer(o =>
        {
            Console.Title = string.Format(
                "{0}: {1}/{2} {3}/{4}/{5}",
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
                Volatile.Read(ref itemsProcessing), Volatile.Read(ref total),
                transformBlock.InputCount, transformBlock.OutputCount, outputBlock.InputCount);
        }, null, 100, 100))
    {
        using (transformBlock.LinkTo(outputBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100); // simulating new item retrieval delay

                Interlocked.Increment(ref total);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsProcessing);

                transformBlock.SendAsync(i).Wait();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enqueued");

        transformBlock.Complete();
        outputBlock.Completion.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Finish");

        timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking `TransformBlock.LinkTo` gets you back a disposable registration. When you dispose of that registration the blocks unlink.

Your `using` scope ends too soon and the blocks unlink before the `TransformBlock` has a chance to empty itself into the `ActionBlock` preventing it from being able to complete. Since the first block doesn't complete the next one doesn't even start completing, let alone finish.

Moving that wait inside the `using` block solves the deadlock:

```
using (transformBlock.LinkTo(outputBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); // simulating new item retrieval delay

        Interlocked.Increment(ref total);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsProcessing);

        transformBlock.SendAsync(i).Wait();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enqueued");
    transformBlock.Complete();
    outputBlock.Completion.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
```

As a side note, you really shouldn't be blocking on async code in such a way. It would be much simpler to use async-await instead of `Wait()`, `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`, etc.

Also, since you're using `PropagateCompletion` you don't need to call `outputBlock.Complete()` explicitly.

Comment: i3arnon, thanks, a lot, it worked. As for the side note, this is just a test app, of course in a real world I would try to use async/await instead of simple blocking. Thanks, again.